# Why doesn't this simple Forth write to the VGA text buffer?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, bootloader, multiboot

I'm trying to write a baremetal Forth for x86-64, booting with Multiboot but without ELF. To check my progress, I tried to get it writing an 'A' character to the VGA text output, using the words I've defined. Here's the NASM assembly:

```
[BITS 64]

LOADBASE equ 0x00100000
org LOADBASE
   
MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC equ 0x1BADB002
MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS equ 0x00010000        
CHECKSUM equ -(MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)

PS_SIZE equ 0x4000
CS_SIZE equ 0x4000

_start: ; in case we're using a custom bootloader
    jmp boot_entry    
    align 4

multiboot_header:
    dd MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC
    dd MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM
    dd multiboot_header ; location of this header
    dd LOADBASE ; where to load the kernel
    dd end ; where to finish loading
    dd 00 ; bss end adress : not necessary
    dd boot_entry ; entry point

%macro next 0
mov rax, qword[rsi]
add rsi, 8
jmp [rax]
%endmacro
     
boot_entry:
    mov rsp, end + PS_SIZE
    mov rbp, end + PS_SIZE + CS_SIZE

    push rbx ; multiboot info
    push rax

    mov rsi, cold_start
    next

%macro pushc 1
    sub rbp, 8
    mov qword[rbp], %1
%endmacro

%macro popc 1
    mov %1, qword[rbp]
    add rbp, 8
%endmacro

%define link 0

%macro DP 2 ; define a primitive (name, label)
    %strlen namelen %1
    align 4

    global name_%2
    name_%2:
        dd link
        %define link name_%2
        db %1
        align 4
    
    global %2
    %2:
        dq code_%2
        align 4
    
    global code_%2
    code_%2:
%endmacro

%macro DC 2 ; define a colon word (name, label)
    %strlen namelen %1
    align 4

    global name_%2
    name_%2:
        dd link
        %define link name_%2
        db %1
        align 4
    
    global %2
    %2:
        dq docol
%endmacro

docol:
    pushc rsi
    add rax, 8
    mov rsi, rax
    next

cold_start:
    dq QUIT

DC "QUIT", QUIT
    dq LIT, 0x41, SHOW, QUIT

DC "SHOW", SHOW
    dq LIT, 0xB8000, BWRITE, LIT, 0x07, LIT, 0xB8001, BWRITE, EXIT

DP "EXIT", EXIT
    popc rsi
    next

DP "B@", BREAD
    pop rax
    mov bl, byte[rax]
    push rbx
    next

DP "B!", BWRITE
    pop rax
    pop rbx
    mov byte[rax], bl
    next

DP "LIT", LIT
    push qword[rsi]
    add rsi, 8
    next

end:
```

Of course, the linked list part of the macros is unnecessary at this point, and can be ignored.

My problem is that this doesn't write anything to the VGA text output. So far, I've ruled out boot issues, as placing instructions to write the 'A' in the `boot_entry` section works fine.

Comment: The cpu is in 32 bit mode when invoked via multiboot. You have 64 bit code.

Comment: Multiboot2 supports 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester), I was writing 64 bit assembly, but the bootloader was only providing 32 bit protected mode.